# Unable to use any Component in my Controller + Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to use different components in my controller;

I declare the use of Components as following in my controller:

```
var $components = array('Email');
```

but when I try to use the Email component in my code, I get the

"Undefined index: email [APP\controllers\cip_surveys_controller.php,
line 33]"

following is the line that is using the Email component

```
$this->Email->to = 'someemail@somedomain.com';
```

The code selection of my controller class is as following:

```
class CipSurveysController extends AppController {
              var $name = "CipSurveys";
              var $uses = array('CipSurvey', 'SurveyResponse');
              var $components = array('Email');
....
....

...

}
```

Please suggest how can I fix this issue. Please note that I am using xampp as development environment.

Thanks,
Jawwad

Comment: does it make an difference if you set the components in the AppController (app_controller.php under /app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it looks like the access to the object is totally wrong

you didnt even give us line 33 (because "email" - lowercase - is not "Email"), where the error occurs.

i bet you used $this->email or $email instead of the correct $this->Email

Comment: Mark, thanks for the response. I later figured out that there was issue in the assignment part of the code (Right hand side of the assignment), where I as picking the email from an object, and that was lower case "email" as you have mentioned. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

After the line:

```
$this->Email->to = 'someemail@somedomain.com';
```

add:

```
debug($this->Email);
```

and tell us what you get. The output will tell you whether you are successfully setting `Email->to`

As Mark says, the text case of 'email' in the error message is perplexing.